# Use jQuery to toggle specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've put together a map of a building and the idea is that when you click on a particular floor, all of the above either appear or disappear.
The issue is that if you click on the 2nd floor for example and all of the above disappear, if you then change your mind and click directly on the ground-floor, the 1st and 2nd floor will disappear, but the ones that had been hidden in the first place will now re-appear, making it a bit of a mess.
Would anyone have any idea as per how to correct that? Thank you all in advance for your time and attention.

```js
//Floors above cicked disappear
$('.floors').click(function() {
  var which = $(this).attr('id');
  if (which == 'basement') {
    $('#ground, #first, #second, #third, #fourth').animate({
      opacity: 'toggle',
    }, 500);
  } else if (which == 'ground') {
    $('#first, #second, #third, #fourth').animate({
      opacity: 'toggle',
    }, 500);
  } else if (which == 'first') {
    $('#second, #third, #fourth').animate({
      opacity: 'toggle',
    }, 500);
  } else if (which == 'second') {
    $('#third, #fourth').animate({
      opacity: 'toggle',
    }, 500);
  } else if (which == 'third') {
    $('#fourth').animate({
      opacity: 'toggle',
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="floors-container">
  <div id="fourth" class="floors">
    <img src="floor.svg" alt="fourth hall map representation">
  </div>
  <!-- #fourth -->

  <div id="third" class="floors">
    <img src="floor.svg" alt="third hall map representation">
  </div>
  <!-- #third -->

  <div id="second" class="floors">
    <img src="floor.svg" alt="second hall map representation">
  </div>
  <!-- #second -->

  <div id="first" class="floors">
    <img src="floor.svg" alt="first hall map representation">
  </div>
  <!-- #first -->

  <div id="ground" class="floors">
    <img src="floor.svg" alt="ground-floor hall map representation">
  </div>
  <!-- #ground -->

  <div id="basement" class="floors">
    <img src="floor.svg" alt="basement-floor hall map representation">
  </div>
  <!-- #basement -->
</div>
<!-- #floors-container -->
```

Comment: Consider using _switch_ instead of _else if_

Comment: Can you show your HTML code too? If you create a snippet would be better. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `opacity` should be a float number from 0 to 1,

Comment: Hi guys, I've just updated the post with the HTML code. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write something like this. And I'd rather use CSS3 transition to make the opacity animation. Anyway:

```
var doAnimate = function (selector) {
    $(selector).fadeOut(500);
};

$(".floors").on("click", function () {
    var which = $(this).attr("id");

    switch (which) {
        case "basement":
            doAnimate("#ground, #first, #second, #third, #fourth");
            break;
        case "ground":
            doAnimate("#first, #second, #third, #fourth");
            break;
        case "first":
            doAnimate("#second, #third, #fourth");
            break;
        case "second":
            doAnimate("#third, #fourth");
            break;
        case "third":
            doAnimate("#fourth");
            break;
    }

});
```

EDIT: SAVE CODE

```
var doAnimate = function (selector) {
    $(selector).fadeOut(500);
};

var ids = ["#basement", "#ground", "#first", "#second", "#third", "#fourth"];

$(".floors").on("click", function () {
    var which = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
    var whichIndex = ids.indexOf(which);
    var selector = ids.splice(whichIndex).join(", ");
    doAnimate(selector);
});
```

FIDDLE ==> https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/tub033wy/

EDIT: CLICKABLE AGAIN
**CSS**

```
.faded{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**JS**

```
  var fadeClass = "faded";

  var reset = function(){
      var selector = ids.join(", ");
      $(selector).removeClass(fadeClass);
  }

  var ids = ["#basement", "#ground", "#first", "#second", "#third", "#fourth"];

  $(".floors").on("click", function() {
      var clicked = $(this);
     if(clicked.hasClass(fadeClass)){
        return;
    }
    var which = "#" + clicked.attr("id");
    var idsCopy = ids.slice();
   var whichIndex = idsCopy.indexOf(which);
   var selector = idsCopy.splice(whichIndex+1).join(", ");
   $(selector).toggleClass(fadeClass);
 });
```

fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/704uqu46/

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks a lot for your help. Really liked your switch statement solution, however it had the same result than mine, and the new edit makes all of the floors disappear at once unfortunately.

Comment: You are right! Apologies as I don't know why it didn't work when I first tried it, but it worked just fine now. However the idea was for all of the floors above the clicked to fadein/out, so would there be a way for the clicked one to remain visible so that when clicked again, all floors re-appear?

Comment: What about using jQuery's fadeToggle() function? I believe that could work, but because the clicked div disappears along with the others above it, I cannot toggle them back to visible

Comment: But from your code, would you know how to prevent the clicked cell from disappearing (so I can then use it to fadeToggle the above back)?

Comment: Thank you Tony but unfortunately the original issue remains for if you click on a floor (say the 3rd), the 4th disappears, but then if you click on another (say the 1st) before the 4th was toggled back to visibility, then the 4th re-appears, however the 3rd and 2nd disappear and from then on appear at different moments. Sorry if it's a bit confusing to understand for it's quite challenging to explain without being face to face

Comment: Well the idea is that if the 4th floor for example is hidden, the user is able to click on the any lower (say the 2nd) to make the 3rd disappear as well without the 4th being visible yet. Only if the user then clicks on the 2nd again (the highest visible floor then), will all of the above floors be visible at the same time. Hope this made more sense

Comment: Yes! That is actually almost exactly that, but if possible the clicked element has to remain visible, and only the above go transparent

Comment: Ok...done. Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/704uqu46/ I also updated the answer, so you can copy from there

Comment: Ah I feel so bad for you helped so much already! But if you make the 4th and then 3rd disappear for example, the 2nd is the highest visible one, and the idea is that then by clicking it (the highest visible floor), all of the hidden ones reappear.

Comment: Now I have to go...It's pretty long to do that...
You can try in the meantime... 
Use ** hasClass()** to check if the clicked element is visible or faded

Comment: Not to worry Toni and seriously thank you ever so much for all your help. I think I'm clearly trying something far too complex for my beginner skills, and should probably settle on what I currently have already.
But once again thank you so very much for all your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: I made a change...what should happen if you click one of the faded elements?

Comment: Hi Tony, I managed to solve it!
I went back to your switch statement and added an if statement for each case which verifies if the above floor is shown or not. If it is, then all of the floors above disappear, otherwise all reappear. And that worked!!
But in any case I wouldn't have been able to without you so thank you ever so much for all of your help and time Tony, really appreciate it.

Comment: Really glad to hear that! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this one you should probably **set** opacity instead of **toggling** it. This will give you much more control on the possible behaviours. A very rude way to implement this could be:

```
$('.floors').click(function() {
    var which = $(this).attr('id');

    //resets everything
    $('#ground, #first, #second, #third, #fourth').css('opacity', 0);

    if(which == 'basement') {
        $('#ground, #first, #second, #third, #fourth').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        }, 500);
    } else if(which == 'ground') {
        $('#first, #second, #third, #fourth').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        }, 500);
    } else if(which == 'first') {
        $('#second, #third, #fourth').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        }, 500);
    } else if(which == 'second') {
        $('#third, #fourth').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        }, 500);
    } else if(which == 'third') {
        $('#fourth').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Phugo, thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. Unfortunately with this code they all disappear but the basement one, and if the opacity is reversed, none do.

Comment: You can convert and optimize this `if-else` to `switch`.

Comment: Yes thank you Milan, Tony's post above gave me that solution which was a good idea, but I still have the same toggle issue.